# Добавляются заголовки вместе с новыми данными

Tags: python, csv

Я хочу добавить новые данные в csv файл, но вместе с новыми данными также передаются заголовки('first_name', 'last_name'...). А мне нужно сделать так, чтобы заголовки были в 1 строке и все, а дальше снизу просто данные под этими заголовками.

Код:

```
import csv

quoting = csv.QUOTE_ALL
def create_csv_file(filename):
    try:
        with open(filename, 'a+', newline='') as f:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(
                f,
                fieldnames=['first_name', 'last_name', 'age', 'city'],
                quoting=quoting
            )
            data1 = input('Имя: ')
            data2 = input('Фамилия: ')
            data3 = input('Возраст: ')
            data4 = input('Место проживания: ')
            writer.writeheader()
            writer.writerow({
                'first_name': data1,
                'last_name': data2,
                'age': data3,
                'city': data4
            })
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

create_csv_file('database.csv')
```

csv file:

```
"first_name","last_name","age","city"
"Ivan ","Ivanov","100","Mars"
"first_name","last_name","age","city"
"1","2","3","4"
```

Comment: Попробуйте убрать это строчку `writer.writeheader()`

Comment: не, тогда вообще заголовков не будет. А мне нужен 1 заголовок сверху над всеми данными

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
import csv
import os.path

quoting = csv.QUOTE_ALL


def create_csv_file(data):
    with open('database.csv', 'a+', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=data, quoting=quoting)
        writer.writeheader()
    user_input()
    return


def user_input()
    try:
        create_csv_file([input('\nИмя: '), input('Фамилия: '), input('Возраст: '), input('Место проживания: ')])
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('\nGood by!')
        exit(0)


def main():
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'database.csv')):
        with open('database.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=['first_name', 'last_name', 'age', 'city'], quoting=quoting)
            writer.writeheader()
    user_input()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Код заголовки не выводит

Comment: В коде, если файла нет, создаётся новый, с заголовками. Если файл есть, в него только дописываются введённые данные. То есть, чтобы у вас в файле были заголовки, нужно, чтобы файла изначально не было.

Comment: Можете условие убрать, тогда при каждом запуске кода файл будет перезаписываться.

Comment: А, извиняюсь, все отлично, все сработало, премного благодарен!!!